# WPF - ComboBox's ItemsSource to have pre-defined set of values

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have combobox in my XAML file. For the ItemsSource of it what I have is a pre-defined set of values.

```
      <ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding MyCollection}
                SelectedItem={Binding SelectedDataItem}
                ............../>
```

I was wondering whether or not it is possible to mention the set of values in the WPF itself, rather than hard-coding it in the ViewModel.

```
            <ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding ItemOne,ItemTwo,ItemThree}
                SelectedItem={Binding SelectedDataItem}
                ............../>
```

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

```
  <ComboBox>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

or create array as resource and refer to it by using StatisResource.

Comment: I think creating an array and then referring to it as a StaticResource is better. Thank You !